# Why dom2Image not working for font icon, if font file loaded from cross domain not captured

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, fonts, cross-domain

```
var node = document.getElementById("myelement");

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        alert(img);
    })
```

While adding catch part in this code

Error while reading CSS rules from https:/.../min.934af7bd4d41e90986f68b2f92548c1e.css SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

If I load the same domain's font file it's working fine

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Add crossorigin attribut to your link where you get css  **crossorigin="anonymous"**

example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:yourLinkHere.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```